# I want a query result using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, codeigniter-2

i have an array result. i want to print 2 rows(product data) in first page.
next 2 rows in second page and so on. if anybody knows this,please help me to solve it

my array

```
$data['product_list']
 foreach($data['product_list'] as $dat)
      {
          echo $dat->prd_id;
          echo $dat->prd_name;

      }
```

Comment: please give solution,why negative marked?

Comment: Please post more information... it is extremely difficult to offer advice with so little information. For example, how are you paging things? What other variables could be used? What is the data source? I can't speak for the two people who have downvoted. These are just my $.02

Comment: use pagination and set limit 2 in your query ...

Answer (score 0):

Better you try with `array_slice();`

```
<?php
$a=array("red","green","blue","yellow","brown");
print_r(array_slice($a,2));
?>
```

Comment: i have mpdf for pdf

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a `foreach` loop on an associative array and then trying to access the the contents as objects by using `->`. I can only given assumption of what you might be doing. If your array is already populated with a name and id like you have described in your `foreach` loop this is how you would access the contents in the loop:

```
foreach($data['product_list'] as $dat)
  {
      echo $dat['prd_id'];
      echo $dat['prd_name'];
  }
```

That is how you would print out the contents providing you had the data stored in your array like so:

```
$data['product_list'][0] = array('prd_id'=>'id0','prd_name'=>'name0');
$data['product_list'][1] = array('prd_id'=>'id1','prd_name'=>'name1');
$data['product_list'][2] = array('prd_id'=>'id2','prd_name'=>'name2');
```

Comment: i want 2 rows in one table,next 2 rows in next table and so on